# Heuristic derivation of Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Is there a heuristic derivation of Schrodinger equation beginning with concepts from classical physics? When I say classical I mean something at the level of an engineer.

Comment: See [Is the Schrödinger equation derived or postulated?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30537/50583) and [How to derive Schrödinger equation?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102708/50583)

Comment: All "derivations" in physics follow from observations. The Schroedinger equation is of importance because it describes several important quantum systems with reasonable accuracy. The most important of these is the hydrogen atom, of course. Beyond that there is no fundamental meaning to it, so your question basically boils down to the question of which quantum systems are correctly approximated by this equation. That is no different from any other equation in physics.